# ExtJS grid alternative with more flexible license?

Tags: javascript, datagrid, extjs, grid

The [ExtJS grid](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html) is awesome.  However, the GPL license is not.  Is there a similar alternative available under a more flexible license?  It must have inline cell editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SlickGrid](http://wiki.github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/examples) easily is the best free alternative I've found.

A few others I've found that aren't quite as good:

- [YUI datatable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_cellediting.html)
- [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html)
- [JqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)